# XOR with multi-byte key in Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm new to assembly (pls correct me if i'm wrong), i'm trying to XOR-ing the byte array with the 4 bytes XOR key, i could do XOR with single byte, but i've no idea how to do if it's multi-byte in assembly. I could do it with python, but with assembly i'm stuck. can anyone help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

shellcode = ("\x31\xc0\x99\x52\x68\x2f\x63\x61")
res = ""
key = '\xde\xad\xbe\xef'.encode('hex')

def xor_strings(s1, s2):
    return ''.join(format(int(a, 16) ^ int(b, 16), 'x') for a,b in zip(s1,s2))

step = 4

for i in range(0, len(shellcode)-1, 4):
    byte = shellcode[i:step].encode('hex')  + '90'*((8-len(shellcode[i:step].encode('hex') ))/2)
    xor_str = xor_strings(byte, key)
    res += "%s," % ','.join([ '0x' + xor_str[ii:ii+2] for ii in range(0, len(xor_str), 2)])
    step += 4

print res
```

i've edited the asm code to read dwords, but still no luck

```
global _start:

section .text
_start:

    jmp short call_shellcode

decoder:
    pop esi        
    xor edx, edx 
    xor ecx, ecx 
    mov cl, slen
    mov edx, 0xefbeadde ; deadbeef

decode:
    xor dword [esi], edx

    add esi, 4
    sub ecx, 4
    jnz decode 

    jmp short EncodedShellcode

call_shellcode:
    call decoder
    EncodedShellcode: db 0xef,0x6d,0x27,0xbd,0xb6,0x82,0xdd,0x8e
    slen equ $-EncodedShellcode
```

Comment: Do it 4 bytes at a time with DWORD-sized `xor` instructions, and incrementing the pointer by 4.  Don't try to do it like you are in Python; that's nasty.  (Although if you need to handle an odd number of bytes, you'd need cleanup code.  Since this looks like shellcode, you can just run off the end and it's fine.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, i tried to modified my asm code (updated the question) to read 4 bytes at a time with DWORD xor, but still no luck, the result is different from the original, i'm not sure what's wrong here :(, you're right this is for shellcode.

Comment: Your Python version isn't rotating every 4th byte by 3 bits, or subtracting.  Of course that's going to be different.  Just remove those 2 instructions.  Oh, and fix the loop bound.  Don't use `sub ecx` inside a loop that also uses the `loop` instruction.  Use a debugger to get that part right.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes! finally it working!!